# How to change svn:externals from bash file non-interactive

Tags: bash, svn, svn-externals

I have multi externals need to be set within a file `externals.txt` and I attempt to change the `svn:externals` from a bash:

```
svn pe svn:externals svn://hostname/branchname -F extenals.txt
```

But the command throws out an error:

```
svn: E205007: None of the environment variables SVN_EDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR are set, and no 'editor-cmd' run-time configuration option was found
```

I don't want to set the `EDITOR` because that would make this action to be `interactive`. I want to this bash script would run automatically.

How to make a bash to change the `svn:externals` without user interactive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
svn ps svn:externals svn://hostname/branchname -F extenals.txt
```

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.propset.html

Comment: Thanks. Seems I didn't notice the difference between `ps` and `pe`. BTW when I set the `-F` for the externals, how could I specify the `message`? The `-F` and `-m` seems to be mutually exclusive.

Comment: Well I found the solutions:
1. `pe` could direct change the remote repository property but it needs user interaction.
2. `ps` could change the repository property automatically but it only works on local work copy. So I have to `check out` it out first. Use `--depth empty` to make it quick.
3. After `ps` I could just `ci` the changes in normal ways.